# Grease Pencil Mesh Warp

Tags: grease-pencil

Is there anything like this smart mesh warp for blender's grease pencil? I know you can move vertices around, but it might be nice to apply a mesh to your drawing to warp like this: https://my.smithmicro.com/anime-studio-pro.html

Comment: A short description of what meshwarp is, would make this question easier to understand, since your link just points to a products home page. (I think the problem is adressed well by the answer though.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do exactly that. For distorting a whole drawing there is the lattice modifier for grease pencil:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLZ6F9mQAdk